# How to get inner error message when starting another job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So I have a pipeline that spawns other jobs (wrapped in a try/catch) like this:

```
script {
    try {
        new_job = build job: 'SomeJob'
    } catch (err) {
        err_msg = err.getMessage()
        error(err_msg)
    }
}
```

and it fails when the spawned job fails, which is as intended. But the spawned job, if it fails will fail with an error message because I used something like:

```
if (badCondition) {
    error("BUILD FAILED BECAUSE OF INVALID CONDITION")
}
```

But in the log of the top level job, it says something like this:

```
SomeJob #11 completed with status FAILURE (propagate: false to ignore)
```

I'd like to somehow get the inner error message, so I can use it to analyze the error without having to go into the inner log. I'm open to other approaches, like setting/returning some env variable. But I'm not sure of the easiest way to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Why bother to catch the exception at all then?

Comment: @hakamairi Sure, like there's no real "point" in catching the fail since I want it to fail anyway, but I figured if I catch the error I can somehow grab the inner error message via the error object. But it doesn't seem like I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out an easy workaround.

In the inner job. Set the error message as an Environment Variable:

```
if (badCondition) {
    error_msg = "BUILD FAILED BECAUSE OF INVALID CONDITION"
    env.BUILD_FAILED_MESSAGE = error_msg
    error(error_msg)
}
```

In the outer job spawn the job while ignoring propagation (so alls job "pass")

```
script {
    new_job = build job: 'SomeJob', propagate: false
    if (new_job.getResult() == "FAILURE") {
        error(new_job.getBuildVariables().get("BUILD_FAILED_MESSAGE"))
    }
}
```

So making sure all the failure conditions set env,BUILD_FAILED_MESSAGE, this is how it can be retrieved in the outer job. Hope this helps others with the same use condition.

Comment: What if the job runs on another node ?

Comment: You mean if the inner job runs on another node? That still works as all the relevant info is saved to the new_job object regardless of what node it's ran on.